# TYPO3 - store custom content element data in own database table

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x

I want to create custom content elements. I know how this works basically. But I asking myself, if there is a way to store the configuration data of this elements in a decent database table?

I only know the way to extend the `tt_content` table and store my data there. But with a bigger amount of elements and fields the `tt_content` would be become bigger and bigger too. I would like to prevent this.

And just before you ask: I don't want to use FluidTYPO3. ;) I just would like to do it with basic TYPO3 functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Don‘t know if there is a nicer way, but maybe you can create your elements with no field definition but with IRRE and min:1 and max:1 - but this is not really a nice way.
The better way is to reuse the fields given in tt_content as often as possible and only add more fields if really needed. 
Maybe you should have a look on EXT:mask and EXT:mask_export - those two are very powerful tools to create custom content elements (EXT:mask) and export them as an own extension (EXT:mask_export) so there is no need for these two extensions in production but only in development.

Answer (score 1):

As you create a content element you will always need to use the database table `tt_content`. Of course it makes sense to use relations to custom records, e.g. if you create elements like tabs, accordions, ...

What you can do is to reuse existing columns as there are - as you said - a lot of those. So reuse fields like `header`, `bodytext`, `image`, ... Take a look at `/sysext/frontend/Configuration/TCA/tt_content.php`. The benefits are

- a bit smaller table which is most of the time not really relevant to performance
- well designed fields including a label whith translations into all languages

You can also reuse a field and its configuration and override it with `overrideChildTca`. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Properties/InlineOverrideChildTCa.html?highlight=overridechildtca in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to have a look at the typo3 extension [mask](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mask). You can create custom contents and map existing tt_content fields to your new elements. It makes sense to reuse the header, bodytext, media, image fields because the backend preview will adopt automatically.

I used it recently and it works really nice! [Here](https://jweiland.net/video-anleitungen/typo3/interessante-typo3-extensions/mask.html) is some resource to jump in (only german)

If you do not need to have indexes on your new fields it is not a big problem to blow up tt_content with new fields. It does not impact the performance so much.

If you need to have new 1:N relations from your content to some child-record (accordion, team-listing, etc), simply add them as [inline elements](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#) (IRRE) and add the field to your [types-string](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Types/Index.html).

If you need to have a new kind of data, that should be filterable, sortable and so on, you should create a new type of record with its own table structure and use extbase plugins to display that data.

As long as you simply need custom contents, you are fine with extending/remapping tt_content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks for this.

In your ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = \Namespace\Hooks\Classname::class;
```

And in Classes/Hooks/Classname:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\SingletonInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler;

class Classname implements SingletonInterface {

    public function processDatamap_beforeStart(&$dataHandler) {
        $datamap = &$dataHandler->datamap;
    }
}
```

Here you have to modify the $datamap to your needs.
Documentation is here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It is explained here https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3, however I prefer extending and reusing tt_content fields.